# Is there a script that check that some users got overlapping permissions in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In order to prove that a team is not seeing another team jobs or folders I need to come up with a measurable solution that validate that.How can I test that each team member don't see each other jobs? Because using the UI to see and comparing with my eyes becomes really difficult with multiple of groups or users for instance.

I am using Jenkins Project-based matrix plugin and latest Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by creating a test user. In case you are using AD or Jenkins own user database, try assigning the same permissions to what you have given for team. This way you will know it for sure.
If there are any such security issues chances, Jenkins will raise a notification highlighting the security issue with that of plugin. Hope this solves the issue.